# Returning wrong percentage

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am trying to calculate how many times two people in a group have the same birthday when given a size of the group. I am also given how many times the simulation is ran. I am trying to return the correct percentage for how many times we have two people share the same birthday out of the given amount of simulations.
I created an array first and then called a method to put the elements in a hashMap which would then show when there are two of the same values in the hashMap. However, I am not getting the correct percentage when running on Android Studio. In fact I am getting a percentage way off. I also declared a global static match variable of type int above this block.

```
/**
 * sameBday: Create a word count mapping from an array
 */
public void sameBday(int[] valueHolder) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 

    for(int number: valueHolder){
        if(!myMap.containsKey(number)){
            myMap.put(number, 1);
        }
        else if(myMap.containsKey(number)){
            myMap.put(number, myMap.get(number) + 1);
            match++;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    double percentage = 0.0; 

    int[] myArray = new int[size];

    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){ 
        Random r = new Random(i); 
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){ 
            myArray[j] = r.nextInt(365) + 1;
        }

        sameBday(myArray);

        if(i == count){
            percentage = (match * (100.0/i));
        }
    }
    return percentage;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure its not `percentage = (match * (100.0/(size * count)));`

Comment: Why are you breaking out of the loop in `sameBday`?

Comment: I am breaking out the loop because once I get two bdays (or values in the hashMap that are the same) I want to stop creating the hashMap and go to the next iteration in the calculate method.

Answer (score 1):

Well your code is full of weird things, but that's OK we all did that. The first thing is Map, you don't need it. You can create just good old *for* loop and by additional check you will not compare the same person (it is `i != j` condition), but if you really want to do this by map you need to at the end of adding number (as key) to map check if some value of key is higher than 1, if true it's a match.

How to do something at the end of loop?

```
if(i == count){
    percentage = (match * (100.0/i));
}
```

No, just do this after loop :)

```
//At the beginning there is int match = 0;

public void sameDayBirthday(int[] birthdays) {
    for(int i = 0; i < birthdays.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < birthdays.length; j++) {
            if(birthdays[i] == birthdays[j] && i != j) {
                match++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}

public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int[] birthdays = new int[size];
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){ //looping through i counts (or 20 counts in this case
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){ //looping through j times every i iteration
            birthdays[j] = r.nextInt(365) + 1;
        }
        sameDayBirthday(birthdays);
    }
    return (match * (100.0/(double) count));

}
```

This code by calling `calculate(23, 1000000)` got me 50.7685% chance, for 22 persons 47.48690%

I am sorry if I offend you I didn't mean it. Leave a comment if you have questions.

Comment: Thank you! Just starting out in Java. This is definitely a lot easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a HashSet and skip the sameBday function:

```
public double calculate(int size, int count) {
    int match = 0;
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){ //looping through i counts (or 20 counts in this case
        Set<Integer> birthdays = new HashSet<Integer>(size);
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){ //looping through j times every i iteration
            Integer birthday = r.nextInt(365) + 1;
            if (birthdays.contains(birthday)) {
                match++;
                break;
            } else {
                birthdays.add(birthday);
            }
        }
    }

    return (match * (100.0/count));

}
```